# How I plot four columns using pandas as shown in the images. the function online permits two variables

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWdHG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osX7Q.png)

How I plot four columns using pandas as shown in the images. the function online permits two variables

Comment: Don't post images of your dataframe. you can check - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And that would be easy, just call `plt.scatter(df.x, df.y)` twice with correct columns from the table